# DataTables hide search input and row count dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

In my ASP.NET MVC application I use jQuery DataTables in order to list my clients. My jQuery version is 3.3.1. I use this code for my DataTable and it works fine:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tbl-data').dataTable();

  // These two lines hides related fields. It works.
  $("#tbl-data_filter").hide();
  $("#tbl-data_length").hide();
});
```

When I translate the DataTable using this code, the localisation works fine but the search input and the row count Dropdown stays visible:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tbl-data').dataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "/Resources/Localisation/French.json"
    }
  });

  // It doesn't work.
  $("#tbl-data_filter").hide();
  $("#tbl-data_length").hide();
});
```

If I call these lines in a manual event, like the `click` event of any control, it works again. I think the `DataTable()` method is asynchronous and before it completes the translation and creation of elements that I want to hide, the lines execute.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your edit has completely changed the goal of the question. I'd suggest reverting the edit and starting a new question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable both these options from the settings; there's no need to hide them separately.

Use the `search` and `paging` options:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
  searching: false,
  paging: false,
  // your other settings here...
});
```

Comment: In fact, I need searching and paging. I modify my question in order to explain my real objective.

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question then, as the whole point of this one was to remove those features

Comment: Ok I will do this.

Comment: I found the solution, I posted it in my other question. Thanks for your help.